# How can I create a query with alternating sorting in rails 5?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following formatting in my database

Products
  - Name
  - Shop Id

with the following records

---

product 1 - Shop 1
product 2 - Shop 1
product 3 - Shop 3
product 4 - Shop 1
product 5 - Shop 2
product 6 - Shop 2
product 7 - Shop 1
product 8 - Shop 1
product 9 - Shop 3
product 10- Shop 3

---

I want to do a query where I bring the result alternating with the "Id Store", something that would look like this:

---

product 1 - Shop 1
product 5 - Shop 2
product 3 - Shop 3
product 2 - Shop 1
product 6 - Shop 2
product 9 - Shop 3
product 4 - Shop 1
product 10- Shop 3
product 7 - Shop 1
product 8 - Shop 1

This listing will still be paged.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time that you want to alternate by threes?  Also, is this for a homework  problem?

Comment: Hi @TomAranda, Thanks for the answer  

It's for a project I'm working on.  

The number of stores is not limited to 3, but varied with 5, 10, 15 or more.  

I could use random ordering, and adjust the hash after the search has been made, but even then it could get into a problem, if it comes only to products from shop 1, it would be a wrong list.  

For this reason, I'm looking for a way to bring the result already alternated by the query

Comment: I think you are going  to have to do this in multiple steps.  I'm not sure one query will work.  I'll have to think on it.

Comment: If you can help me, I will be very grateful, as I have been trying to solve this problem since yesterday, and I have not been able to reach a valid solution until now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to do this is Rails. You will want to group all of the different shops into separate arrays. Then use a nested loop to pop the first record off of each array until they are all empty. I would guess most of this would happen in Rails with only one or two queries to the database.

Something like this:

```
# Initialize product grouping hash
grouped_products = {}

# Produces hash of product arrays.
# Each array contains all of the products for a shop.
Products.all.order(:shop_id, :name).each do | product |
  grouped_products[product.shop_id] = [] if grouped_products[product.shop_id].nil?
  grouped_products[product.shop_id] << product
end

# Now we turn all of our grouped arrays into enumerators
grouped_products.each_key do | key |
  grouped_products[key] = grouped_products[key].each
end

alternating_products = []

# Here we build the alternating products array
loop do

  # Get the next product from the top of each grouped array
  grouped_products.each_key do |key|
    # Add the next product from the current array to the alternating array
    begin
      alternating_products << grouped_products[key].next
    # If at the end of the current array, remove it from the hash
    rescue StopIteration
      grouped_products.except! key
    end
  end

  # Stop looping when all arrays are empty and removed from hash
  break if grouped_products.empty?
end

alternating_products
```

I have not tested the above code, so it may need  some tweaks.

This requires looping through the entire dataset twice.

Since this returns an ordered array, you can paginate fairly easily.  For example: to get the first 10 records use `alternating_products[0..9]`.  To get the second set of 10 records use `alternating_products[10..19]` and so forth.

Comment: Test your code here and it worked perfectly to switch the products, but there is still a problem that I can not solve, as the list has to be paginated, if the first page only comes from a store, it could not switch because only there will be products from a store

Comment: My fear is that it will be very heavy thinking on a large scale, but for now I will do it this way, thank you very much for the help = D

Comment: True, it is not very efficient, but it is the best solution I could think up at the moment.